# Need to use Notepad++ RegExp to find and remove characters between curly brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

Looking to remove the "#" character between {} in the sample text below

Sample Text:

```
\(C##nH##{##2##n##+##1}O\)
```

Expected output:

```
\(C##nH##{2n+1}O\)
```

What have I tried?

```regex
\{[#].*\}
^.+?(?=##\w##)##\K|##(?!$)
```

Would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as off-topic/SuperUser-question, please check [Are text editor regex questions off topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311935/8967612)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `(\G(?!^)(?=[^}]*})|\{)([^#{}]*)#+`
**Replace With**: `$1$2`

**Details**:

- `(\G(?!^)(?=[^}]*})|\{)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` in the replacement pattern): end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) that is followed with any 0+ chars other than `}` and then followed with `}` or (`|`)  `{` char
- `([^#{}]*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any 0 or more chars other than `#`, `{` and `}`
- `#+` - one or more `#` chars

Notepad++ demo & settings:

[image]

Comment: A brief note why I did not use `\K`: a lot of people only experiment with regex in Notepad++ to see how well it fits their data, and then use there patterns in target environments, and not all of them support `\K` operator (e.g. Java, .NET, Python `re`).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following pattern:

```regex
(?:\{|(?<!^)\G)[^#\r\n]*\K#+(?=.*\})
```

..and replace with an empty string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUTP4i/3)**.

**Breakdown:**

```
(?:             # Beginning of a non-capturing group.
    \{          # Matches the character '{' literally.
    |           # Alternation (OR).
    (?<!^)\G    # Asserts position at the end of the previous match.
)               # End of the non-capturing group.
[^#\r\n]*       # Matches zero or more characters other than '#' or line breaks.
\K              # Resets the starting point of the match (only include what comes next).
#+              # Matches one or more '#' characters.
(?=.*\})        # A positive Lookahead to make sure the `}` character exists.
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. I am noticing an issue if there is a ## after {}. E.g. \(C##nH##{##2##n}O##2\). This is getting converted to \(C##nH##{2n}O2\) instead of \(C##nH##{2n}O##2\). I want to limit the replacement to only the characters inside {}.

Comment: @Spykar I couldn't reproduce this. I'm getting exactly the output that you're expecting. See the demo: https://regex101.com/r/Rn8iCr/1.

Comment: Not sure why the ## in O##2 is getting removed in my Notepad++. I really appreciate your help. Your solution is working well otherwise :)

Comment: @Spykar You were right. I figured out why and updated the answer accordingly. Basically, `[^}]*` was consuming line break characters as well so the Lookahead worked even if the `}` character is in a different (following) line. Check the fixed version.

Comment: Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

I think a possibility would be:

```
(?:\{|\G(?!^))[^#}]*\K#
```

And replace with nothing.

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/09VL2z/3)

---

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

  - `\{` - Match a literal curly bracket.
  - `|` - Alternation/OR.
  - `\G(?!^)` - Assert position at the end of the previous match but not at start of the line.
  - `)` - Close non-capturing group.
- `[^#}]*` - Match anything but hashtag and closing curly brackets zero or more times.
- `\K`- Resets the starting point of the match.
- `#` - An hashtag.